# How to perform two functions in one that differs by only one line?

Tags: python

I have a function that calls two others. The two other functions are almost identical except for one line with the transformation of a dictionary.

```
def func2(..):
    ...
    dictionary = ..
    filtered = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value} # by filtering 
    ...

def func1(..):
    ...
    dictionary = .. 
    # function continue without filtering the dictionary 
    ...

def main(..):
    ...
    func1(..)
    func2(..)
```

Is there a better way to allow me to have only one function instead of two? And execute these two functions with just `filtered = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value}` to add or remove.

But another way than putting a boolean as argument of the function.

```
def func(..,filter=True):
    ...
    dictionary = ..
    if filter:
        filtered = {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value} # by filtering 
    ...
```

Because for programs nested in several other functions it is necessary to add the boolean in arguments of several function which do not use it I do not find that very practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answers, here is what is the professional way to solve the problem. The keyword you are looking for is *Template Method*. This is a design pattern that falls under *Behavioral Patterns*. My following explanation is taken from the book: *Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software by E. Gamma, R. Helm, R. Johnson, J. Vlissides*

**Template Method**

Quote from said book:

> The Template Method should be used when common behavior among
> subclasses should be factored and localized in a common class to avoid
> code duplication. This is a good example of "refactoring to
> generalize" as described by Opdyke and Johnson [...]. You first
> identify the differences in the existing code and then separate the
> differences into new operations. Finally, you replace the differing
> code with a template method that calls one of these new operations.

Let me break it down to your problem in a simple pythonic way:

```
# Our dictionary
dictionary = dict(a=True, b=False, c=True)

# The filter function that implements a specific behavior
def myfilter(dictionary):
    return {key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value}

# A function that contains the code that will always be called. 
# This is our basic structure. 
# func is a function. Its default value is the identity function, i.e. simply
# returning its argument 
def common(dictionary, func = lambda t: t):
   
    # Do something here with the dictionary that is ALWAYS done
    # ...
    
    # Call the passed method on the dictionary. If no method was explicitly 
    # passed, then the default identity function is called, which returns the 
    # dictionary unchanged.
    return func(dictionary)
    
print(common(dictionary)) # Returns {'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': True}
print(common(dictionary, myfilter)) # Returns {'a': True, 'c': True}
```

So you can't avoid to implement two functions. The advantage of the presented solution is that you do not have to duplicate any code. For more and more detailed information, I recommend a look at the aforementioned book.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't define a directory in func1 or func2, just give `dictionnary` in argument of your function by defining it in `main`.

It gives:

```
def func(dictionnary, ..):
    ..


def main(..):
    dictionnary = ..
    func({key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value}, ..)  # = func2(..)
    func(dictionnary, ..)  # = func1(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the dictionary as an argument to the function, so that when needed, you can filter it before the function is called.

```py
def main():
    dictionary = {}
    func(dictionary)
    func({key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() if value})
```

Keep in mind that this creates a copy of the dictionary, so changes made to it inside the second `func()` call will not be reflected on `dictionary` if you use it again.